# Flash AS3: saving/loading the positions of all the children of a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I would like to know how to save and load the X and Y position of all the children of a MovieClip.

I have a project with a save and load button.

They save and load the X and Y position of the MovieClip's child.

```
save.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler3);

function fl_MouseClickHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void
{

var mySo:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("SaveData");

mySo.data.my_x = mc2.x;
mySo.data.my_y = mc2.y;
mySo.flush();


}

loader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{

var mySo:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("SaveData");


mc2.x = mySo.data.my_x;
mc2.y = mySo.data.my_y;

}
```

This however only saves and loads the last clicked MovieClip child.
How can I change it from only saving and loading the last clicked MovieClip child,
to saving and loading all the MovieClip children?

Comment: That guy asked the same question a few weeks back and got the same answer. Total duplicate. How many times does he need to ask the same question and get the same answer?

Comment: I asked a similar question last week, and I was not able to use the answers I recieved. This time however my question is answered so you don't have to worry about me asking the same question again.

Comment: This is the exact same answer, the only difference in this second one is that all the code is written for you. You asked the same question a second time not because you did not get a correct answer the first time but because you needed an answer that you could copy and paste. You are basing the correctness of the answer on how perfectly a copy and paste will work.

Comment: This site is among other things, used to get help for programming questions. If someone would explain
step by step so I could learn the answer on my own, then nothing would be better. But I searched for a solution/tutorial
for hours and found none that were spot on. This helped me solve my question, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will always save "mc2" positions, you will need to run a loop on numchildrens of the movieclip and put their positions in an array, and then access them in the same way. Here is a code example

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var mySo:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("SaveData");
save.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler3);
loader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var clippositions:Array = new Array();
    var child:MovieClip;
    for(var i:uint=0; i<this.numChildren; i++)
    {
        if( this.getChildAt(i) is MovieClip )
        {
            child = this.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip;
            if(child)
            {
                clippositions.push( { clipname:child.name, my_x:child.x,my_y:child.y } );
            }
        }
    }
    mySo.data.clippositions = clippositions
    mySo.flush();
}

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var clippositions:Array = mySo.data.clippositions;
    if( clippositions != null )
    {
        var child:MovieClip;
        for(var i:uint=0; i<clippositions.length; i++)
        {
            if( this.getChildByName( clippositions[i].clipname ) is MovieClip )
            {
                child = this.getChildByName( clippositions[i].clipname ) as MovieClip;
                if(child)
                {
                    child.x = clippositions[i].my_x;
                    child.y = clippositions[i].my_y;
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get the error message: Access of undefined property numchildren.

Comment: That corrected the error, but now when I click the save button I get:    TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: I edited the answer, but you need to adjust it bit as per your setup. The code assume all the children are movieclips.

Comment: I thought all the children were movieclips? I tried to move the code somewhere else in relation to my other code and now I get no error but the  save and load buttons do not work.

Comment: not sure how you are setting it up, I tested the above code and it worked fine, I added check for you to only save movieclip. Hope it helps.